# html doesn't import the javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

Here´s my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/EdvinHedblom/Library/MobileDocuments/com~apple~CloudDocs/javascriptfile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

The problem is that it doesn't take the functions from path. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure it's referring the proper path??

Comment: To load from your file system prefix "file://" to the path. i.e. `file:///Users/...`

Comment: @JunaidAhmed - That is a MacOS path. C:/ won't work.

Comment: com~apple~CloudDocs seems  to be a directory containing spaces or more characters than what you copied 

Can you show us the function you need from the js? maybe the problem is how you wrote it?

Comment: HTML file is on your localhost, or in remote server?

Comment: html is on localhost

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your index.html and js file folder same disk.

2.and just remove / in src at the beginning.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Users/EdvinHedblom/Library/MobileDocuments
/com~apple~CloudDocs/javascriptfile.js">
</script>
```

or just save your `javascript.js` file in folder name called "js"

and link your js file this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/avascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether that js file exists in the given path , if so 
try to use like this

src="Users/EdvinHedblom/Library/MobileDocuments/com~apple~CloudDocs/javascriptfile.js"

Answer (score 0):

If you load a file from the filesystem, then the prefix `file://` should be used.
If an absolute path is used, don't forget the additional slash representing the root of the filesystem (in total three slashes).

In your case the HTML should then look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Users/EdvinHedblom/Library/MobileDocuments/com~apple~CloudDocs/javascriptfile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```